# HTML Play mp4 video on Spoiler click

Tags: html

How do I make so that a .mp4 video plays when I open the spoiler? When I press the Show/Hide button I want the video to start!

```
<div id="spoiler4" style="display:none"> 
<h1 style="color:red;">Testing!<h1/>
</div>
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler4') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler4') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler4') .style.display='none'}">Show/hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="spoiler4" style="display:none"> 
<h1 style="color:red;">Testing!<h1/>
</div>
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="$('#spoiler4').show();">Show/hide</button>
```